# Limitations on sms verification android firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, sms-verification

I need to trigger a notification on my Android app from firebase. Unfortunately, user USER1 in a remote area does not have an active internet connection.

Now I send SMS verification from another mobile ADMINUSER for USER1 mobile number and then, as a result, can I use it to trigger the notification? If I use ADMINUSER for 100 different numbers will firebase detect and stop admin User as fake request SMS verifier?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#security-concerns) the method you propose would have major security flaws and there is no mention of Firebase blocking the device which would be used for making multiple requests.